# How to register script with null value for version?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

Can someone explain the version argument in `wp_register_script()`? According to the codex it is `added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes`.

It also says if the `$ver` argument is set to `null`, no version is added and if `false`, the currently installed version of WordPress is added.

How do I set the `$ver` argument to `null`? I thought I had in the code I'm using below but it's adding the currently installed WordPress version as the version number.

```
function add_ajax_script() {
    wp_register_script('ajax-implementation', '/wp-content/themes/codilight-child/scripts/ajax-implementation.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-implementation');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_script' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally specify the version number as `null`:

```
function add_ajax_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-implementation', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/scripts/ajax-implementation.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-implementation');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_script' );
```

An empty string, `''` is not the same thing as `null`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did try null but I had it in quotes. Also, I'm curious to know what is meant by cache busting purposes?

Comment: Cool! Yeah, `'null'` (*in quotes*) is simply a string and is different than `null` (*[the special value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)*). *Cache busting* is a technique used to override the browser's cache for a particular file. This is handy for when you want to force the user's browser to update a stylesheet (for example) after you (the developer) have modified it.  By changing the version number from what it was before, the browser will automatically load a fresh copy of the file.